# justify text where each span tag is a word

Tags: html, css

I have a table that has this div with the transcription-text class, this #Text# in it generates a 'span' tag and each tag is a single word. When the table decreases the width, the 'transcription-text' div ends up not causing the words to skip lines when reaching the limit of the div.

```
<div class="transcription-text">                                                   
   #Text#                                                 
</div>
```

As each word is a span tag inside this div, I need it to align automatically according to the width of the transcription-text class, as if it were a bootstrap "row", but with multiple span tags. Below the entire code of the template.

```
<div class="panel-body">
                <div class="panel-transcription-alert alert alert-warning" style="display: none;">
                </div>
                <table class="table table-transcription">

                    <tr class="transcription-row #Custom_TranscriptionItemType_Name# base-repeater-item hide" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" title="#TitleOriginalText#" data-content="#OriginalText#" data-trigger="hover">
                        <td class="col-sm-12 text" data-start="#Start#" data-end="#End#" data-startrelative="#StartRelative#" data-endrelative="#EndRelative#" data-transcription-item-id="#Id#">
                            <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between; flex-wrap: wrap;">
                                <div class="transcription-item">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-play-loop" style="display: none;" onclick="playLoop(this)">
                                        <i class="fas fa-play"></i>
                                    </button>
                                    <div class="transcript-time-container">
                                        <div style="display: table-row">
                                            <div class="transcript-time-item start" style="">
                                                #StartFormatted#
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="transcript-time-item" style="">
                                                #EndFormatted#
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="transcript-text-container">
                                        <div style="display: table-row">
                                            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                                                <span class="badge badge-default">
                                                    <i class="#Custom_TranscriptionItemType_Badge#"></i>
                                                    <span>#SpeakerSide#</span>
                                                </span>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="transcription-text">                                                   
                                                #Text#                                                 
                                            </div>
                                            <div style="display: table-cell; padding-left: 7px; display: none; width: 800px;" contenteditable="true" class="transcription-text-edit"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div style="display: flex;">
                                    <div class="container-badge-edited-transcript" style="margin-left: 10px; display: none;" title="Texto editado">
                                        <div class="badge badge-warning">
                                            E
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="transcription-intentions" style="margin-left: 10px;" title="Intenção">
                                        <div class="badge badge-info">
                                            <span>#Intention#</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="transcription-sentiments intention" style="margin-left: 10px;" title="Sentimento">
                                        <div class="badge #SentimentTypeBadge#">
                                            <span>#Sentiment#</span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="transcription-categories" style="display: none;">
                                <hr />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: What is your `.transcription-text` CSS `display` property is set to?

Comment: I solved the problem, unfortunately it's on the company's computer, then I put the solution here. But it has a display block, the problem was another CSS interfering with responsiveness! lol